# Axios won't set the "Cookie" header on request

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios

I'm using the following setup: axios for sending XHR requests, which are sent to webpack dev server and proxied by it to the production server.

The thing is that I need the `sid` cookie to be passed with each request to the server (i.e. the `Cookie` header to be present on each request). But axios for some reason won't set it at all.

[image]

And it seems like it doesn't matter at all whether `withCredentials` is set to `true` or not (both globally or for a specific request); also Chrome doesn't allow to set the `Cookie` header with the value I need manually.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; // - doesn't help
```

```
axios: axios.create({
  baseURL,
  withCredentials: true, // - doesn't help either
}),
```

```
await requestService.axios.post(`projects/${project.id}/close`, null, {
  withCredentials: true, // - same result
});
```

```
await requestService.axios.post(`projects/${project.id}/close`, null, {
  headers: {"Cookie": document.cookie}, // - blocked by the browser
});
```

**How do I overcome this?**

*And yes, I understand that there will probably also be issues with the proxy layer, but for now it would be greate to achieve at least having the Cookie header set for the original request.*

---

### UPD

> Please show the Set-Cookie header from the response.

This is the response I get from the server. As far as I understand the flow, it returns a new `sid` each time if I don't provide it with the request. And *that* is the issue for me, since this `sid` is used as a sort of identification mechanism to prevent modifying several parts of the app by some other user.

[image]

> You need to consider the HttpOnly attribute, same-site-origin, CORS, ....

I don't know the mechanics of HttpOnly attribute and why should I consider it at all, would be great if somebody could explain it to me if it's crucial.

Considering CORS. Again, I'm using webpack-dev-server proxying in order to overcome CORS-related issues. So I'm pointing my requests to the proxy server, which, in turn, sends them to the production server.

> you should probably get a warning in the developer console

Nope. Some warnings do present (come on, it's a development process :)), but none of them are related to the issue for sure.

---

### UPD 2

Added this to my webpack config:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "mypath": {
      ...
      cookiePathRewrite: "",
    }
  }
}
```

Doesn't seem to change much. The path is rewritten, though the Cookie header still doesn't present on the request:

[image]

Comment: Please show the `Set-Cookie` header from the response. You need to consider the `HttpOnly` attribute, same-site-origin, CORS, .... you should probably get a warning in the developer console.

Comment: @DanielW. Sure, give me a moment, please. I'll notify you after editting the question.

Comment: @DanielW. Updated the question, take a look please.

Comment: Will be happy to provide any additional info (as long as as it doesn't require me to violate NDA)

Comment: The `Path` on the cookie doesn't appear to be an ancestor of the path the request is being made to, so it doesn't apply.

Comment: The `sid` cookie is sent with `HttpOnly`, it means you can't access it via JavaScript. The Ajax request should automatically use the `Cookie` header when there is a cookie that it accepted before. Why doesn't the client accept the cookie? I suspect the `path`, it doesn't fit your `/`.

Comment: Does it mean I should somehow tweak my webpack dev server's proxy config? If yes, then in which way?

Comment: @DanielW. What do you mean by saying "the client doesn't accept the cookie"? I can see it present on the Application tab -> Cookies in my devtools.

Comment: [The Path attribute indicates a URL path that must exist in the requested URL in order to send the Cookie header.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) - your path is `/dev/default`.

Comment: @DanielW. Can I somehow wildcard it for development purpose? I mean, would rewriting the path from `/dev/default` to, say, `/*` make the thing?

Comment: Tried to use `devServer.proxy.cookiePathRewrite: ""` - doesn't seem to work, even though there's no "Path" present on the cookie anymore :|

Comment: @Quentin updated the config, the path is removed completely now, but still no effect in general. Please, take a look at the UPD 2.

Comment: @smellyshovel — Paths have a default value of the current URL IIRC. Set it to / explicitly.

Comment: @Quentin magic. Works. You both saved my day. Thank you very much. I may later post it as an answer if you're not against it. Thank you again.

Comment: @DanielW. By the way, does this ("The sid cookie is sent with HttpOnly, it means you can't access it via JavaScript.") statement mean that I shouldn't be using `withCredentials: true` at all since the cookies are passed automatically? I removed it already and it seems working fine, though might have missed something.

Comment: @smellyshovel If it works without setting it to true, you shouldn't enable it. Read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).